# showing the function |z| is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So i need to shwo that f(z) = |z| is analytic. All i really have avavailable to me really are the cauchy riemann equations. So with that being the case i guess the assumption that the partials are continuous is present.

But how do i show analyticity for this function?

Following the advice from some earlier posts i saw, i should convert the function into u+iv form, but all all that gives me is (u^2 + v^2)^1/2.

What if i treated the modulus as a positive and negative case?

Comment: $|z|$ is NOT analytic.

Comment: Note that "$u + iv$ form" means splitting the _value_ into real and imaginary parts. Here you have $u(x, y) = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ and $v(x, y) = 0$.

Comment: No complex function taking only real values is analytic, unless it is constant.

Comment: I had a feeling it wasn't, i just was not sure if i shold have treated the  magnitude portion exckusively as the real portion of the complex value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Recall that
>
> 1. A complex function $f=u+iv:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is **analytic at a point $z_0=x_0+iy_0$** if there is a neighborhood $V=B(z_0,r)$ (say) of $z_0$ such that $f$ is differentiable (in the complex sense)  at every point $z$ of $V$.
> 2. A necessary and sufficient condition that a complex function $f=u+iv:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is **differentiable at $w=a+ib$** is that
>
> ($i$)  all the partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x$and $v_y$ exist and continuous at $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$
>
> ($ii$) the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ must hold at $(a,b)\in \Bbb R^2$

For your problem $f(z)=|z|$ and so $u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=0$. Clearly it can be observed that the condition $2(i)$ is failed to hold at $(0,0)$ for $u$. So $f$ is not analytic at any point of the complex plane.

Answer (score 7):

$f(z) = |z|$ is not analytic. So you are being asked to prove something that is false.

Answer (score 2):

A function $F(z)$  is analytic if $\dfrac{\partial F(z)}{\partial \bar{z}}=0.$ We have $f(z)=|z|=\sqrt{z \bar{z}}$. It is clear that $\dfrac{\partial f(z)}{\partial \bar{z}} \neq 0,$ so  $|z|$ is not analytic.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it is analytic then the square of it is also analytic. But the square is $z\bar z$ which is everywhere non-analytic by checking the dbar derivative